# А как можно получить информацию из другой страницы?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

И возможно ли через JS / JQuery ?

Имеем:

— http://example_1.com - где размещен `<div id="div-1">111</div>`

— http://example_2.com - где размещен `<div id="div-2">222</div>`

— http://example_3.com - где размещен `<div id="div-3">333</div>`

Как можно собрать эту информацию из разных страниц?
Скажем, для мониторинга чего-либо, если таких страничек сотни-тысячи: собрать все div-ы и их внутренности на одной странице.

*Cобрать - я и сам соберу. Главный вопрос в том - возможно ли через какой-нибудь код написать что-то подобное:

```
url('http://example_1.com').getElementById("div-1").innerHTML;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

То что вам надо достигаетсья технологиями  **AJAX** и **jQuery**

Вы можете загрузить  страницу и спарсить информацию из внешней страницы С **HTML** контентом и с интуитивными  **CSS** селекторами

Приведу пример простого get запроса

```
$.get("anotherPage.html", {}, function(results){
  alert(results); // будет показывать HTML из anotherPage.html
  alert($(results).find("div.scores").html()); // показывает div  "scores" внутри results
});
```

Для внешних доменов надо использовать **PHP**